# Multiple SQL Server inserts fail, but go unnoticed in Mule

Tags: sql-server, mule

When I run multiple insert queries together into a SQL Server database with Mule, if the second insert fails, it doesn't insert a row, and won't show as a failure in the flow or logs.

We use variables to collect together different SQL statements to insert into a header and detail table. I noticed last week that in some cases, the header record was there but no detail. There was nothing in the logs for this.

After some investigation it appears that Mule will take the result of the first SQL insert as the return code, regardless of whether the resulting SQL inserts worked or not.

I've tried changing this to a BULK UPDATE but i still get the same result.

Edit - code included for a sample insert. 4 insert statements, 3 will be successful, 1 will fail, but will simply pass back as successful -

```
insert into highjump.t_import_order(status,idoc_number,datetime_created,datetime_processed,error_message,wh_id,order_number,order_type,order_subtype,is_vas,is_shrinkwrap,is_mhe_packhold,is_consolidation,is_nonmhe_packhold,is_full_case,ship_to_account,ship_to_name,ship_to_address1,ship_to_address2,ship_to_address3,ship_to_city,ship_to_state,ship_to_zip,ship_to_country,sold_to_account,sold_to_name,sold_to_address1,sold_to_address2,sold_to_address3,sold_to_city,sold_to_state,sold_to_zip,telephone_number,sold_to_country,stock_pool,discount,box_type,service_level,telephone_number_alt,dest_type,carrier_code,route_code,inv_cat,cust_order_date,expected_ship_date,expected_delivery_date,dsv_tracking_number,postage_cost,carton_contents_type,unit_total,total_before_discount,total_after_discount,carton_cubing_indicator,req_proof_of_delivery,payment_type,is_cms,carrier_override_type,sales_org,pack_note_preference,shipper_order_id,master_order_number,currency_code,store_code,order_method,dsv_reference,email_address,ship_complete_flag,replen_type,carton_content_flags,partner_profile) values 
(N'Z',N'0000000629673252','2019-04-12 09:57:38','2019-04-12 09:57:38',null,N'WST',N'6412210697',N'MCR',N'STD EU',0,0,0,0,0,0,N'MCRSHPTODE',N'Dave Smith',
N'888415936',N'PACKSTATION 432',null,N'Koettgenstr. 8',null,N'13629',N'DE',N'MCRSLDTODE',N'MCR SOLD TO DE',N'High St.',null,null,N'Street',null,N'BA330YA',null,
N'GB',N'MC01',0,N'BAG',N'10',null,N'RE','',N'01',N'W','2019-03-29 11:38:13','2019-03-29 11:38:13','2019-03-29 11:38:13',null,0,N'001',2,null,null,'91',1,
N'MCR CON - UK Orders',1,'1',null,N'N',null,N'623611121','GBP',null,null,null,N'Smith@arcor.com',null,'R',N'F', N'WWMULESFTH');

insert into highjump.t_import_order_cms 
(order_id,delivery_from_date,delivery_to_date,pin_number,cms_location,cms_delivery_endpoint,cms_comm_preference,cms_dont_despatch_before,cms_market,cms_brand,is_gift,gift_message,loyalty_number,cms_dest_type,cms_time_delivery,cms_day_delivery,cms_customer_type,carrier_service_name,special_instructions) values ((select top(1) order_id from highjump.t_import_order where order_number='6412210697'),'2019-04-03','2019-04-03',null,N'432',N'PACKSTATIONPACKSTATION',null,null,null,N'CLA',null,null,null,N'PUDO',null,null,null,null,null);

insert into highjump.t_import_order_detail 
(order_id,line_number,item_number,order_quantity,customer_item_number,ratio_pack_group,is_ratio_pack,ratio_pack_qty,uom,retail_price,freight_class,sales_order_number,customer_order_number,dsv_price_discount,customer_item_colour,price_paid,currency_code,customer_item_size) 
values ((select top(1) order_id from highjump.t_import_order where order_number='6412210697'),00010,'261392464080',1.000,null,null,null,null,'U','0.0',null,N'623611121000010',N'623611121',null,null,99.95,null,null);

insert into highjump.t_import_order_detail (order_id,line_number,item_number,order_quantity,customer_item_number,ratio_pack_group,is_ratio_pack,ratio_pack_qty,uom,retail_price,freight_class,sales_order_number,customer_order_number,dsv_price_discount,customer_item_colour,price_paid,currency_code,customer_item_size) 
values ((select top(1) order_id from highjump.t_import_order where order_number='6412210697'),00020,'261394324080',1.000,null,null,null,null,'U','0.0',null,N'623611121000020',N'623611121',null,null,89.95,null,null);
```

Comment: There's no BULK UPDATE. There's BULK INSERT that works with files. You haven't posted any code (Java or SQL) either or explained what you do, so it's impossible to say why it eats up errors. If you want multiple statements in a SQL script to execute as one transaction you'll have to explicitly use `BEGIN TRAN/COMMINT TRAN` etc. If you want to control what gets returned, you'll have to use [TRY CATCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Apologies for the lack of code. Will update now.

Comment: What exactly does "1 will fail" mean? And how to you know this?

Answer (score 0):

Structurally, these SQL queries seem to be fine. It is unclear to me why and how any of these queries would fail (or would not insert any data). It should just work fine, as far as I can see.

In the end, when you execute these queries in SQL Server Management Studio, they should all return value 1:

```
select count(*) from highjump.t_import_order where order_number = '6412210697';
select count(*) from highjump.t_import_order_cms where order_id = (select top (1) order_id from highjump.t_import_order where order_number = '6412210697');
select count(*) from highjump.t_import_order_detail where line_number = 10 and order_id = (select top (1) order_id from highjump.t_import_order where order_number = '6412210697');
select count(*) from highjump.t_import_order_detail where line_number = 20 and order_id = (select top (1) order_id from highjump.t_import_order where order_number = '6412210697');
```

Comment: Structurally the queries are fine - but in the 'import_order_cms' table, the delivery_endpoint column has a limit of 9, which is exceeded when inserting 'PACKSTATION' in there.

Comment: Aha. I see. That could not be derived from the information you provided. So you identified the issue. Well, fixing it is perhaps another issue. If you are the one (or one of the people) responsible for the database design and maintenance, you may decide to enlarge this column's length. Or you may decide to use an abbreviation. Or you may contact the system designers, provide them your feedback and ask them to enlarge this field. I am afraid there is little I can help you with here. I have no clue which requirements, use-cases, user stories etc. may get broken when this field will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Use transaction for multiple insert queries execution. In multiple SQL queries suppose one query gives error then it will be roll back.

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
       //Here you will write multiple insert/delete/update queries 
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

Comment: And how will this help? OP has clearly (perhaps mistakenly but we cannot know) that the result of the query execution is "success", not "error". In such a case, the only logical path is to commit the transaction which will have the same effect as not using any transaction.

Comment: This works - but it will simply roll back the entire transaction (all inserts) but not show as a failure within the mulesoft console logs. It would seem that when all 4 are run together, the reason code is returned from the result of the first insert, and ignores the rest.

Comment: Inside the catch block you can write the exception details to file or any table for the error log details.